# Pass information from UIAlertView linked to an annotation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mapkit

i am new to Xcode so please forgive my question if it is silly

i have an annotation linked to an UIAlertView box which have two choices (close , direction to here)
the second button should open the apple maps application and instantly provide turn by turn navigation to the user.

now my problem is that i have many annotations on my map, and when pressing on every annotation the user must get the option to get navigation. so i don't have a fixed MKPlacemark, i need to pass the information from the pressed annotation to MKPlacemark so the MKMapItem get the desired heading location.

my code is :

My Annotation method which will show a  UIAlertView:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control{
// get reference to the annotation to access its data
VBAnnotation *ann = (VBAnnotation *)view.annotation;
// deselect the button
[self.mapView deselectAnnotation:ann animated:YES];

// display alert view to the information
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:ann.title message:ann.info delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"close" otherButtonTitles:@"direction to here", nil];
[alert show];
}
```

Here my UIAlertView button actions:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
if([title isEqualToString:@"direction to here"])
{        

//now here i tried a fixed coordination, but i need to pass the actual coordination pressed by the UIAlertView
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    coordinate.latitude = 24.41351;
    coordinate.longitude = 39.543002;

    MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:nil];
    MKMapItem *navigation = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:placemark];
    NSDictionary *options = @{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeWalking};
    [navigation openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:options];

}
}
```

Here is a sample of my annotation list

```
NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
VBAnnotation *ann;


//Annotations List

// Mecca Pin
location.latitude = MEC_LATITUDE;
location.longitude = MEC_LONGITUDE;
ann = [[VBAnnotation alloc] init];
[ann setCoordinate:location];
ann.title = @"NewHorizons Institute";
ann.subtitle = @"English and computer training center";
[annotations addObject:ann];
[self.mapView addAnnotations:annotations];
```

Of course i have a class called VBAnnotation

Thanks ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to remember the `VBAnnotation` object so that the alert view delegate method has access to it. You could use `objc_setAssociatedObject()` to associate the object with the alert view just before you show the alert view, then use `objc_getAssociatedObject()` to retrieve the object when you handle the user's response to the alert.

[This article](http://labs.vectorform.com/2011/07/objective-c-associated-objects/) has more information on Obj-C associated objects. The file to import to get at the functions is this:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

If the `VBAnnotation` object can be identified with a numeric ID or index of some sort, a simpler method would be to store that ID or index in the `tag` property of the alert view - `UIAlertView` is a subclass of `UIView` and thus inherits that property.

Comment: Thanks ...My VBAnnotation  object holds 5 properties:
    // Coordinate
    //title
    //subTitle
    //informations
    //name
but the only thing i need to pass is the coordination ... 
Thanks ... the article is really helpful

Comment: @AliRaslan If this answer helped solve your problem it would be nice if you accepted it. Otherwise you can write your own answer and accept that.

Comment: I'm sorry :$ I am new to the site, and didn't know about the accept button :)